# How can an audio segment report an integrated loudness (LUFS) greater than 0

Tags: audio

According to my very rudimentary understanding of the [ITU-R BS.1770 standard](https://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-r/rec/bs/R-REC-BS.1770-4-201510-I!!PDF-E.pdf), I *thought* that the LUFS (L<sub>K</sub>FS) value for any audio signals should not ever go positive.

However, there is a 5-second segment from an audio file I have whose integrated loudness level is +1.28 when measured using `ffmpeg`, and +1.44 when measured using [`pyloudnorm`](https://github.com/csteinmetz1/pyloudnorm):

(stereo, source audio resampled at 48000 Hz, 16-bit signed little-endian integer waveform PCM)

```
[Parsed_loudnorm_0 @ 0x7fc245008680]
{
    "input_i" : "1.28",
    "input_tp" : "0.86",
    "input_lra" : "2.90",
    "input_thresh" : "-10.16",
    ...
```

How is this possible? Could this be an issue related to the implementations (i.e. `ffmpeg` and `pyloudnorm`) and not the algorithm itself?

I concede that I don't fully understand the math in the algorithm, and so if the algorithm does allow a positive value in certain situations, please explain.

Comment: Are your sample valued bounded by +1 and -1?

Comment: @Jazzmaniac Do you mean the .wav file itself? Right now it's a signed 16-bit integer LPCM file so it can't overflow.

Comment: yes, but the values in that LPCM file, are they mapped to [-1; +1], or to some other range, after being read into your software? The fact that it's PCM doesn't say anything about the scaling!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am using `ffmpeg` which doesn't offer the kind of configuration you are describing. Can you explain more on the meaning of this mapping and how it could potentially affect the calculation of LUFS? If it's of any relevance: if I transcode the signed 16-bit .wav into a 32-bit floating point .wav first, then 1. I can see using `numpy` that there are samples beyond [-1, 1] and 2. I get a different (even greater) LUFS using `ffmpeg`: at 1.32 instead of 1.28.

Comment: well, there's bytes in your file. Whether a pair of bytes `0xFFFF` is interpreted as -32768 or as -1.0 is fully up to your software; but it does scale the output

Comment: @MarcusMüller Are you speculating that by misinterpreting two `int16` integers as a 32-bit floating-point number, my software could be seeing unusually high amplitudes and therefore gave an incorrect LUFS? If so, then what I was saying was that the softwares I was using were fully aware that the file they were handling was a _16-bit, signed, little-endian, integer_ waveform PCM file, and could guarantee that no implicit type casting or byte-alignment was taking place. This is a non-issue because I wasn't working with raw bytes.

Comment: I might look into that later, but wondering if it has anything to do with K-weighting? I roughly remember it's perceptual so it might have a boost around 3kHz (as Fletcher-Munson curves do). In this case for that frequency content you might get values higher than 0.
Another idea- is the audio stereo? This might give you another boost of 3 dB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did download this annoying video and analyzed the part with a vuvuzela. You should take a note that:

- This part is clipped
- **The audio is stereo**

And that pretty much solves the mystery.

[image]

If you calculate the loudness for each of the channels separately you will get approximately -1.4 LUFS. Since this is a stereo track you add those levels together. For incoherent sources, you would roughly expect a 3dB of boost. Lo and behold, the total loudness calculated from the stereo track is approximately 1.6 LUFS (+3.2).

If you think about it, this makes perfect sense. What happens if you take one of those clipped channels and play it back through a speaker? You gonna get some SPL. Now, add a second speaker and play the other channel, you would expect to be even louder (3dB louder to be precise). Therefore LUFS accounts for that.